# Should we consider Audioslave a continuation of Rage Against The Machine, Soundgarden, or neither?

Tags: rock, hip-hop, alternative-rock, punk, soundgarden

I've always felt that Audioslave is too clean, too accessible, too 'mainstream' to be considered a continuation of either RATM or Soundgarden. I enjoy it to an extent, but for me, it doesn't resemble punk or grunge very much. Perhaps it is closer to modern hip-hop sonically, except with non-auto-tuned vocals. Compared to Soundgarden, it's not very ambitious or experimental.

Should we consider Audioslave a continuation of Rage Against The Machine, Soundgarden, or something 'new'?

---

**Audioslave**

[*Like A Stone*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QU1nvuxaMA)

[*Be Yourself*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WC5FdFlUcl0&list=PLRam0XIF5XatuR1DR0VP3lDDxRfZ5QoQb)

**RATM**

[*Killing In The Name*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWXazVhlyxQ)

[*Guerilla Radio*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rm1nCYOZB-s&list=PL2EbESdPFdo4-nv0UV04MznK6a-21tZ1a)

**Soundgarden**

[*Black Hole Sun*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mbBbFH9fAg&list=PLk9tVsYIPaaFC3zQK_Aj12cgsXYiWGWIX)

[*Spoonman*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0_zzCLLRvE&list=PLk9tVsYIPaaFC3zQK_Aj12cgsXYiWGWIX)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any band that takes members from multiple previously established bands should always be considered a new band.  If Cornell wanted these songs to be Soundgarden songs, he'd have done them with Soundgarden.  But, at the same time, when you have a certain writing style which permeated your previous band, you're always going to sound a little like that band.

So, in summary, Audioslave wasn't a continuation of any band, it was its own entity that combined elements of various bands to create their sound.